# Add prototype of a fuction

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some question about my node.js project.
What I'm trying to do is, add additional functionality to a function.
So, I added new functionality using prototype, but it failed.
Below is my current code.

[ someFeatures.js ]

```
const functionFoo = new Function()
const functionBar = new Function()

module.exports = { functionFoo, functionBar }
```

[ addFeatures.js ]

```
// Import fuction
const { functionFoo, functionBar } = require('./someFeatures.js')

// Add additional feature
functionFoo.prototype.addtionalFeatureA = foo => {
    return someFunction(foo)
}

// Add additional feature
functionBar.prototype.addtionalFeatureB = foo => {
    return someOtherFunction(foo)
}


module.exports = { functionFoo, functionBar }
```

[ Other files will use this feature ]

```
const { functionFoo } = require('./someFeatures.js')

const aaa = new functionFoo()
aaa.addtionalFeatureA('bbb')
```

The result is 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')'

Is there any solution to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you import from `addFeatures.js` instead of `someFeatures.js`, does it work?

`const { functionFoo } = require('./addFeatures.js')`.

Comment: something is missing here. according to your code, the only place where this error can occur is in `addFeatures.js` because that's the only place you access `prototype`, but that code should never be executed, because that file never accessed.

Answer (score 1):

change `new Function`
into empty function

```
let yourFunction = function () {}
```

and change this

```
function.prototype.additional = foo => { ... }
```

to this

```
function.prototype.additional = function (foo) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the info that `new Function()` has no prototype but I can't reproduce it, not even in strict mode. I know that arrow-functions have no prototype but that doesn't matter either. The problem is neither with the prototype nor the method on the right. The error message implies that `functionFoo` or `functionBar` doesn't exist at all.